# Word to describe someone who makes you feel uncomfortable

Tags: meaning

It's more like unsettling and discomforting but not threatening like daunting or menacing.

Answer (score 4):

How about *creepy*?

From [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/creepy):

> (informal) having or causing a sensation of repulsion, horror, or fear, as of creatures crawling on the skin

Comment: Yeah, something like "That guy is really creepy" would be a fairly normal usage of the term.  Been idiomatic in the US for 40 years, at least, and probably crosses age groups pretty well (though I'm sure teens have some other terms).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean they make you only feel uncomfortable try:

*[Discomfiting](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/discomfit?showCookiePolicy=true)*

> to make uneasy; disconcert

*[Disconcerting](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/disconcert?showCookiePolicy=true)*

> to upset the composure of; embarrass; confuse

If you mean you don't want to be around them, try one of these:

*[Repulsive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repulsive)*

> causing or occasioning repugnance; loathsome; disgusting or distasteful

*[Repugnant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repugnant)*

> 1. repellent to the senses; causing aversion
> 2. distasteful; offensive; disgusting

*[Odious](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/odious)* has always been a favorite:

> offensive; repugnant

Comment: These sound a bit strong for someone who is just "unsettling and discomforting".  Not saying they're wrong.  But all three have very strong negative connotations that seem to go beyond what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @A.Ellett "Repulsive" is an alternate meaning for "creepy", even by the definition in the other answer... so I don't know that I see a difference in the strength other than that creepy is more commonly used.

Comment: "creepy" can be used in contexts where "repulsive" could send the wrong message.  You can tell someone, "what you said is creepy" or even that they look a bit "creepy".  But if you said, "repulsive" you've made a much stronger or even inappropriate comment.  For example, a halloween costum can be creepy, but not repulsive at all.

Answer (score 1):

*[disturbing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disturbing)*:

> adjective
>   1. upsetting or disquieting; dismaying:
>
> Origin
>   1585-95; *[disturb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disturb)* + -ing
>
> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to interrupt the quiet, rest, peace, or order of; unsettle.
> 2. to interfere with; interrupt; hinder: 
>      *Please do not **disturb** me when I'm working.*
> 3. to interfere with the arrangement, order, or harmony of; disarrange:
>      *to **disturb** the papers on her desk.*
> 4. to perplex; trouble:
>      *to be **disturbed** by strange behavior.*
>
> verb (used without object)
>
> 5. to cause disturbance to someone's sleep, rest, etc.:

*Perhaps Ray is a **disturbing** fellow, because he is disturbed himself.*